# Bind multiple models to one View Controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.4

I am starting to give up on laravel for not being able to follow a certain pattern that I always have been taking for granted !!

let's assume I have the example from this link 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#introduction

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = $this->users->find($id);

    return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

This *user* model is bound to that controller to be shown in the view. 
What if I need to inject another model, let's call it *plane* which is independent from users model (no DB relation). 
So that I have both of them listed in the same view.

In Angular for instance I could create multiple components on the same page and each have their own independent controllers and models.

Comment: Your example does not really use any sort of binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel supports contextual binding.

It also has shortcuts for binding database models:

**Model binding**

In your `RouteServiceProvider` you can have:

```
Route::model("user", App\User::class);
```

Then your route declared as:

```
Route::get("/users/{user}","UserController@show");
```

And your controller:

```
public function show(User $user) {
   //$user->id is based on the {user} route parameter
}
```

**Other contextual binding**

```
Route::bind("plane", function ($id, RouteInfo $routeInfo) {
      // Get the plane object based on the given $id and optionally the extra route info parameters
     return $planeObject;
});
```

Your route can be declared as:

```
 Route::get("/planes/{plane}", function (Plane $plane) {
      //$plane will depend on passed parameter
 });
```

Laravel also supports normal binding:

In your `AppServiceProvider` you can have:

```
 $this->app->bind(Plane::class, function ($app) {
      //Make a plane class object
     return $planeObject;
 });
```

Then in your controller method (or any place where Laravel allows dependency injection to occur) you can do:

```
public function show(Plane $plane) {
   //Plane is the globally declared binding
}
```

You can also combine the two e.g:

```
Route::model("user", App\User::class);
$this->app->bind(Plane::class, function ($app) {
      //Make a plane class object
     return $planeObject;
 });

 Route::get("/users/{user}","UserController@show");

 public function show(User $user, Plane $plane) {
   //$user->id is based on the {user} route parameter and $plane is resolved using the service container
}
```

Comment: in this one : 
    $this->app->bind(Plane::class, function ($app) {
            //Make a plane class object
            return $planeObject;
     });
How do I retrieve the object from the mysql database created by artisan make:model in order to return it

Comment: @mahmoudfathy `return Plane::find(/* some id you need */)` since there's no context in that code you should only use it if you always want to get the same `Plane` object. If you need to add contextual information but not from the route check [the binding basics](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding)

Comment: I assumed I might use Plane::findall() , well ? , I need all the entries anyway

Comment: @mahmoudfathy You can't do that. `all()` returns an array. Arrays are primitives in PHP so they can't be bound (it would be silly to always get the same array whenever you needed to use an array for anything).

Comment: Actually I need the entire array, I don't need one element. I pull the array from the model database, it changes via the db.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can bind multiple models with laravel like this :

```
public function show(User $user, Plane $plane)
{
    return view('user.plane', compact('user', 'plane')]);
}
```

and as @apokryfos said your example does not have any binding in the controller,

this is an example for the corresponding route:

```
Route::get('/fakeRoute/{user}/{plane}', 'FakeController@show');
```

link example:

```
yourSite.com/fakeRoute/1/25
```

Comment: Or if you prefer not to use compact: `['user' => $user, 'plane' => $plane]`

Comment: yes I know, I did not show a reproducible code. I am still learning laravel, and I am examining its features, I couldn't find a similar example. There are many binding examples in the very same link I wrote there which also gets me overwhelmed, don't know to this point which one should I use if I need multiple models. But now that I know it's possible from you I got what I need for now,  I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, One controller can send request to multiple models to update single view, So yes you can use multiple models in one controller